# Vision API error out stating 'com.google.api.gax.grpc.ApiException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED'

Tags: grpc, grpc-java, vision-api

I executed the Vision API for text extract from an image, on running the sample code it is errorring out with he below error stack.

> May 28, 2017 10:46:48 AM io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl 
>   INFO: [ManagedChannelImpl@543788f3] Created with target vision.googleapis.com:443
>   com.google.api.gax.grpc.ApiException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
>   End
>       at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ExceptionTransformingCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(ExceptionTransformingCallable.java:109)
>       at com.google.api.gax.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:52)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1764)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:456)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:817)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:753)
>       at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:634)
>       at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:466)
>       at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:442)
>       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.close(ClientCallImpl.java:481)
>       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl.access$600(ClientCallImpl.java:398)
>       at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:513)
>       at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:52)
>       at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(SerializingExecutor.java:154)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
>       at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:545)
>       ... 13 more

I run the code from Eclipse in my local system.

I tried the below items as found in some forums;
1) Degraded all the netty* jars from 4.1.6 to 4.1.3
2) Degraded google-cloud-vision-0.10.0-beta.jar to google-cloud-vision-0.9.4-beta.jar
3) Adding the pom.xml
4) Adding GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS in windows environment variable - pointed to the JSON file downloaded for the Service Account

Comment: How long is the deadline configured to be?

Comment: Hi Carl, I am new to GCP. I was trying to figure out the configuration but was not successful. Can you help me on where to find the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting deadline while creating stub

```
blockingStub = SomeGrpc
    .newBlockingStub(channel)
    .withDeadlineAfter(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

and see if this helps